# How to combine two different linux commands?

Tags: linux, hash

I use the following command to get the MAC address of the system.

```
ifconfig | grep enp0s20f6 | awk '{print $5}'
```

The following command is used to get the hash of the string:

```
echo -n "string to be hashed"| md5sum | awk '{print $1}'
```

I need to get the hashed string for the MAC address by combining both of these commands.

I tried the following, but didn't work.

```
ifconfig | grep enp0s20f6 | awk '{print $5}' | md5sum
```

Answer (score 1):

```
md5sum /sys/class/net/eth0/address | awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address | md5sum
```

Replace eth0 by the name of your interface. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
md5sum < /sys/class/net/eth0/address
```

This command also helps to get the md5sum of mac address